# Route/Redirect to another page in new tab using useNavigate

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid and it has an event `onSelectionChanged`, which make the row clickable. When I click on row below function is called.

```
const onSelectionChanged = useCallback(() => {

  const selectedRow = gridRef.current.api.getSelectedRows(); //get the row data

  let navigate = useNavigate();   //import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
  navigate('/Detail', { state: { data: selectedRow[0]} });  //navigate to detail page

}, []);
```

The function navigates to the detail page and the state is passed. But `navigate()` calls the `Detail` page in same tab.

I want to open the page in new tab. Is this possible using this method? or there is another way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-router` isn't supposed to help preserve state when opening things in a new tab. In fact, fundamentally, `react` isn't supposed to help do this.

I'd approach this in two ways:

- If the data is simple enough, pass it as a query or path param using `windows.open(window.open("http://link?key="+ value +"&key2="+ value2 ..."); )`
- Look into other state management methods like `localstorage` or [something else](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-manage-state-in-your-react-apps)

Comment: `windows.open` looks like I can use this and pass `id` instead of state object. Thanks!